# When a person is unable to recognize their own emotions, what is the name for it?

Tags: emotion, terminology

What is the name for inability to recognize one's own (not other's) emotions?

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to *alexithymia*?

> Alexithymia is defined as a personality construct characterized by the sub-clinical inability to identify and describe emotions in the self. The core characteristics of alexithymia are marked dysfunction in emotional awareness, social attachment, and interpersonal relating. Furthermore, individuals suffering from alexithymia also have difficulty in distinguishing and appreciating the emotions of others, which is thought to lead to un-empathic and ineffective emotional responding.

Source: https://www.disabled-world.com/health/neurology/alexithymia.php